# Consider the elastic-net optimization problem

Tags: optimization

Consider the elastic-net optimization problem:
    $$\min_{\theta}||y-X\theta||_2^2+\lambda[\alpha||\theta||_2^2+(1-\alpha)||\theta||_1].$$

I was told that I could turn this into a Lasso problem, using an augmented version of matrix $X$ and vector $y$. However, I do not see how to do that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are we supposed to show it or are you?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I do not see how to turn it into a Lasso problem. Do you happen to know?

Comment: You will find the how in the original elastic net paper https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf . I'll make you dig through it and fill in the details.